# How to determine the value of a decoupling capacitor across a Peltier device?

Tags: filter, h-bridge, peltier, cooling, bypass-capacitor

I have a TEC device (Thermoelectric Cooling device/peltier device), and I have seen several datasheets recommend placing a bypass capacitor across the TEC device (i.e. parallel to the TEC, and in addition to the second order low pass filter on either side of the TEC).  Why is this needed? Does it act as an HPF to provide a low impedance path for ripple in order to increase efficiency of the TEC device? Also, how do I determine the value of this capacitor?

[image]

Comment: What is a TEC device?

Comment: Thermoelectric Cooling Device @LeonHeller

Comment: You should call that a low pass filter anyway, because the meaningful output is the voltage across the TEC. Its purpose is to smooth the output from the H bridge driver, together with Ca, Cb, La and Lb. Why a TEC should need that? I don't know, and thanks to the LP characteristic of a thermal device I'd have guessed you should not need that.

Comment: Additionally Ca and Cb also provide filtering so if these are large enough in size, you would not need the other Capacitor. I guess although the TEC doesn't need a filtered voltage, the Capacitors might help filtering out some spurious frequencies which are caused by the switching stages.

Comment: Could you add links to these datasheets you alluded to?

Comment: Page 14 of the [MAX8520/MAX8521 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8520-MAX8521.pdf) says a few words about "the differential-mode filter capacitor", implying that a larger capacitor reduces the ripple on the current through the TEC, which improves efficiency. Alas, I don't see enough information there to actually pick a real capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the  value of the decoupling capacitor between the TEC you will have to see the effect of the thermal noise on the switching done by the OSC in your driver usually a PWM.

The TEC works on the reverse SEEBECK effect,the change in the temperature on the two surface,causes the current to flow,this condition is reversed by using a driver where the current flow is modified,

The Usual ICs Design will Use Some pins to sense the Output(V) at the TEC terminals,
and a resistor placed to act as a V-I converter often called Current sense.
**Please Notice there are lot of variants in the market each with different design here I will prefer only DC based ICs so if yours is a bit different please bear with me.**

The TEC current values are controlled and switched by sensing these Output (**Often called Ouput sense**).

To make the system more regulatory the switching can be made in two mode,(one faster and the other slower (**there are still some IC using one switching frequency,and yet some providing upgrade based on your designed ckt** ).

Mostly Companies use PWM  based switching,these frequency switches of TEC uses OPAMP Oscillators.
Typically they have a band of `<-20deg C to >80deg C`,hence there are lot of thermal and thus current variation to account for,

Often the Switching to be done is influenced by the Thermal variation these switching are basically done with a help of Oscillator,hence  to cancel thermal noise ***Capacitors*** are used.

When generating cold, the TEC moves the heat away from its cold side to ts hot side as the current flows into the positive terminal. The higher the current, the larger the amount of the heat is moved. During this process, heat is generated on both sides. When the current is increased to a certain level, the heat generated by the current on the cold side equals the heat being moved away from the cold side, the temperature on the cold side stops dropping, i.e. the TEC’s thermal output power becomes zero.

Most Ics has max 6-8A current limit.

Comment: Adding an oscillator on both sides of the TEC?  I have never seen a reference design with an oscillator on a TEC.  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Actually I meant Oscillations as ripples on the both side rather than Oscillators,which have to be accounted to compute the value of decoupling capacitor,I would really like which Ic you are using I have changed my answer.Sorry for wrong reference.